# How call Procedure in Mssql on Specific Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014-express

I am Using SQL server 2014 and **i want to run a procedure automatically** as per scheduled time.. 
I want to Sync Data from One Database to Another Database...

**It is any Option in Express to Scheduled to call a specific procedure**....

Comment: You could create an SQL server job and schedule it

Comment: SQL-Express has no option to schedule a job.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server Express edition, there isn't a SQL Agent for scheduling. You can use Windows Task Scheduler and use sqlcmd to execute your stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Provided you don't have complex scheduling needs but only need something to run, say, once a day at a fixed time, you can combine a few features.

You can create a stored procedure that never ends, with a body something like:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WAITFOR TIME '22:00'

    EXEC SomeOtherTask /* parameters, etc */
END
```

You put this procedure in `master`, and then call [`sp_proc_option`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql) on it to mark it as a startup procedure.

Then restart your SQL Server instance and, at the appointed time, `SomeOtherTask` should be executed.

Note that you wouldn't want to over-use this technique - it keeps a connection permanently tied up just waiting for time to pass. Much easier (but of course with a cost) is to move up to a more fully-featured edition. You're starting to do things that are causing you pain - such as job scheduling and what appears to be some form of replication which are built into higher level editions. You may have outgrown Express edition.